# Red rectangle below filename in eclipse after modification?

Tags: java, eclipse, egit, m2e

Today i have been busy bringing an old project back to live, i converted into a m2e project (1 maven root project with multiple modules). Always a big task because not all libraries are backward compatible. But at the end of the day i got most things running.

At that point i decided to put everything in my local git repository. No problem here.

But to my surprise i now see different behaviour when a file changes. In other projects when a file is marked changed a little arrow " > " will appear in front of the filename.

But now a little " * " appears and the filename is surrounded by a red rectangle (it goes away when i commit). See my screenshot:

[image]

Anybody knows why this is happening and which eclipse (kepler) feature/plugin is responsible? I already looked through the git options but none seem to be responsible for the red rectangle and star symbol.

Comment: Possibly a conflict?

Comment: My first thought also because of the red highlight, but http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations and http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State doesn't say anything about a red highlight nor the star nor can i configure it and it only seems to appear on modified file and disappears after commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem! It was aptana studio that did draw this red highlight. It seems that aptana has its own git version. This version automatically attaches itself to any imported project from a git repository. Took me some time to figure that out. The solution was quite simple. Windows > preferences > team > Git (first one is the aptana one) > disable check box "automatically attach our git support ...". Now disconnect projects in eclipse, next delete them (not file contents) and finally re import the project from the git repository. Now the egit (eclipse one) will attach itself to the projects and everything is fine :-)